# form_for display as both block and inline elements (ruby on rails, css)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to have some elements displayed as block and some as inline in `form_for` block? I have few elements in the `form_for` block. The first one I want to be displayed on one line by itself and the other two (collection_select and submit) I want to be displayed on the same line together. Is this possible?

Here's my code:

```
<div class="container form-group">
  <%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :problem_id, :value => @problem.id %>

  <%= f.label :content, "Add Comment:" %>
  <%= f.text_area :content %>

  <%= f.label :comment_type, "Comment Type:" %>
  <%= collection_select(:comment, :comment_type_id, CommentType.all, :id, :name, prompt: false) %>

  <%= f.submit "Add" %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

I want collection_select and submit on the same line basically. How can I do this?
I assume this to be a CSS question, but I could be wrong. Also I'm using bootstrap-sass gem, if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

Have a looksee at that. You could then manually add `<br/>` tags? That's be the quick and dirty.

When you're adding a class to a form in rails, though, you need to do

```
<%= form_for @comment, html: {class: 'form-inline', role: form} do |f| %>
```

You could also just override the elements that are returning on you. The labels might be doing that to you. Do you know how to check that in the browser?

Comment: Hey, thanks. Looks like this is what I need. For some reason I can't get it to work though... I'll keep trying, this has to be it.

Comment: Ok I figured it out. though my solution still sucks somewhat, but actually form-inline doesn't work. Instead I used form-horizontal with specific col-xs-# and col-xs-pull-# classes.

Comment: Nice! bootstrap is a great tool, but there's often hacking involved, lol

Comment: @fatuhoku the role? Needs some quotes it looks like.